# explanation needed: ternary operator in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

The line in question is `return pFile.exists() ? true : null;`. As it does not raise any compilation error, what is the explanation for this. It ended up raising `NPE`.

```
import java.io.File;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    boolean accept = accept(new File(""));
    System.out.println("accept = " + accept);
  }
  public static boolean accept(File pFile) {
    System.out.println(pFile.exists()); // prints: false, so pFile is not null
    return pFile.exists() ? true : null; //this line should throw compilation error
  }
}
```

`pFile` is not `null`; a `File` is instantiated as you can see. But obviously the file is not there. The question is not about `pFile`.  I am interested in how the operator is dealing with `null`.

Comment: Why not just return `pFile.exists()`?

Comment: Replace the body of accept(File pFile) method with the following: `return (pFile == null) ? false : pFile.exists();` or instead of using the ternary operator, you can just say `return (pFile != null) && pFile.exists();`.

Comment: Please see my edit. yes, i could write `return pFile.exists();`

Comment: @Kowser: I just realized that the ternary operator is making this act differently than just `return null` which would give you an incompatible types error at compile time. You should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @styfle: i didn't know that :-S. That is why I had to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You code is equivalent to:

```
public static boolean accept(File pFile) {
    System.out.println(pFile.exists()); // prints: false, so pFile is not null
    Boolean tmp = pFile.exists() ? true : null;
    return (boolean) tmp;
}
```

On other words, the type of the conditional operator is `Boolean` in this case, and then the value is being unboxed to return a `boolean`. When `null` is unboxed, you get an exception.

From [section 15.25](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25) of the Java Language Specification:

> Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2. The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).

I believe that's the case that's applicable here, although I'll grant it's not as clear as it might be.

Comment: @Jon, to be honest, i find your answer correct but oververbose and not exactly to the point. You cited ternary operator specification, which, in fact, has nothing to go with the problem -- which is auto-unboxing of some expression `pFile.exists() ? true : null`.

Comment: @Piotr: But it relies on the type of that expression being `Boolean`, which is then unboxed. So it's not the execution of the conditional operator which is failing - it's the conversion step *after* that execution. I think that's an important aspect.

Comment: @Jon, no doubt that the condition (`?:`) runs smoothly. This is what i meant saying that the fact some `?` and `:` is in use has little importance.... Anyway, thank you for pointer to JLS :)

Answer (score 2):

You return `Boolean null` from function defined as returning `boolean` (a primitive type; note small `b`). The `null` value is automatically unboxed, and casues NPE.

Comment: So it promotes the expression to type `Boolean` and boxes and unboxes the `null`...?  Just... yuck.

Comment: It converts result of `pFile.exists() ? true : null` (being `null`) to `boolean` using auto-unboxing. Auto-unboxing of `null` yields NPE

Answer (score -1):

Actually, an *empty string* is being used to create a `file`. This results in a empty `abstract pathname` with no prefix(or directory) and an empty name sequence. So windows is unable to create a `file`. This in turn is throwing a `NPE`